# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test testng meaven

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

please help for the following error:

[image: please help for the following error]

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Explain what you have done and add all error messages as text (not image).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks from your property definitions:

```
mvn clean install -Dtest=com.qa.dontknow.test -Denv=qa
```

See [surefire:test `<test>`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test):

> [...] so you can just type -Dtest=MyTest to run a single test called "foo/MyTest.java". [...]